# Какой знак препинания нужен перед ВСЕ?

Tags: пунктуация, недопустимая-метка

Какой знак препинания нужен перед ВСЕ в предложении?

> Бурая залежь базальта, бездонная
> глубина неба, призрачные нагромождения
> льдов, казавшиеся сверхъестественными
> ... все это создавало впечатление
> сказочной страны.

Нужно тире ставить или что-то другое, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Бурая залежь базальта, бездонная
> глубина неба, призрачные нагромождения
> льдов, казавшиеся сверхъестественными
> ... все это создавало впечатление
> сказочной страны."

Перед "всё это" нужно тире. См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113 :

> **§ 34.** Обобщающее слово, стоящее после однородных членов, отделяется от
> них знаком тире: *Поручни, компасы,
> бинокли, всякие приборы и даже высокие
> пороги кают — всё это было медное*
> (Пауст.); *И эти поездки, и наши с ней
> разговоры — всё проникнуто было
> щемящей, безысходной тоской* (Бек.).

Плюс нужна запятая после "сверхъестественными", закрывающая причастный оборот.

ИТОГО:

> "Бурая залежь базальта, бездонная
> глубина неба, призрачные нагромождения
> льдов, казавшиеся сверхъестественными,
> -- все это создавало впечатление сказочной страны."

Comment: Молодец, slava1947, Вы очень добросовестно и аккуратно переписали мой ответ, добавив в свое пояснение то, чего не было в первоначальном Вашем ответе, а именно запятой, закрывающей причастный оборот

Comment: СПАСИБО за то, что похвалили! Но добавляя к своему ответу (практически мгновенно после его отправки!) дополнение, я не мог видеть  Вашего будущего ответа, так как его ещё не было и в помине. Виновато в минутной задержке небольшое зависание моего компьютера. Пришлось даже его перезагружать. Пожалуйста, не обижайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!:)

Answer (score 2):

После "казавшиеся сверхъестественными" надо поставить запятую, чтобы "закрыть" причастный оборот, и тире как знак после однородных членов перед обобщающими словами "все это". То есть Ваше предложение должно выглядеть так:  "Бурая залежь базальта, бездонная глубина неба, призрачные нагромождения льдов, казавшиеся сверхъестественными, - все это создавало впечатление сказочной страны."

Comment: Спасибо большущее за помощь!